# How to select all columns of a table with unique combination of just some of them in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table named "Products" with the following structure:

```
id | name   | variety      | t_min | t_max | entity
====================================================
1  | hake   | salmo salar  | -5.27 | 10.3  | entity1
2  | salmon | null         | -2.45 | 12.9  | entity1
3  | cod    | gadus morhua | -4.98 | 11.98 | entity1
4  | hake   | salmo salar  | -7.87 | 9.35  | entity1
5  | hake   | salmo salar  | -2.76 | 8.46  | entity1
```

The desired result I would want is:

```
id | name   | variety      | t_min | t_max | entity
====================================================
1  | hake   | salmo salar  | -5.27 | 10.3  | entity1
2  | salmon | null         | -2.45 | 12.9  | entity1
3  | cod    | gadus morhua | -4.98 | 11.98 | entity1
```

I want to select all the columns of the table but avoid repeating rows that have the same *name+variety* in this case. Just using DISTINCT clause doesn't work because if I use it I just can select the columns I want to be unique, so how can I do it?

Comment: How do you decide which hake row you want? Lowest id?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: It's MySQL 8.0.25, @jarlh. And I don't mind which hake row it takes, I just want to select one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by name, variety order by id) rn
  from products
) r 
where r.rn = 1
order by r.id
```

Comment: It perfectly works, thank you. Just one thing, is there a chance to not add the rn column to the result of the select?

Comment: @Álex select individual columns instead of *

Comment: instead of * , select columns by name.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select * from ( select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER
BY id) AS row from Products ) as a where row = 1
```

hopefully it will give you the unique data.